# BottomNavigationView - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview, android-developer-api, android-bottomnavigationview

I have used images as icon but I dont want them to look grey when they are not selected. It should look same as picture whether its active or not. What should I do?

```
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
```

Thanks
[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this in your XML file in the BottomNavigationView part

```
app:itemIconTint="null"
```

Or add this to your java file **after** defining your BottomNavigationView (with the findViewById)

```
//Replace BottomNavView with your nav bar id
BottomNavView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: I tried this but i get this error

\res\layout\activity_home.xml:44: AAPT: error: 'null' is incompatible with attribute itemIconTint (attr) color [weak].

Comment: try adding this to the activity file ( the java file) ´BottomNavView.setItemIconTintList(null);´ **after** defining you BottomNavView with the findViewById

Comment: @Nina you have to use `@null` instead of `null`, but in this way you are removing the default selector.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't know what to do. You could try setting the tint for each separate item. Something like this: Menu BVMenu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
BVMenu.setItemIconTintList(null);
BVMenu.findItem(R.id.Your_menu_item)name).setIcon(yout_drawable);

Comment: ^^this would be in the java file of yor activity where you initialize theview components, can be on the OnCreate, remember to use the findViewById to define your bottomNavigationView first

Answer (score 0):

A long way to achieve it

```
mBottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Then do the designs yourself. Don't forget to separate the buttons as clicked and not clicked.

Example Button XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Clicked-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homeclicked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!--Not Clicked-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homenotclicked" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

And add them to the view: Example bottom_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/homebuttons"
        android:icon="@drawable/homebuttonxml />

 <!--Other Buttons...-->

</menu>
```

And finally, Link view to bottomnavigationview

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView    
     android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
     app:elevation="0dp"
     app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">  
   
</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

Comment: Am new to android development i dont know where to put these codes : (. Can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

The default color used by not selected items is based on the `colorOnSurface` color.

Just use:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationViewThemeOverlay"
     ....  />
```

with:

```
<style name="BottomNavigationViewThemeOverlay">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Otherwise you can define your custom selector:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
           app:itemIconTint="@color/bottomnavicontint"
           ../>
```

with:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="1.0" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="@color/..."/>. <!-- not selected -->
</selector>
```

Comment: @AshutoshYadav which version are you using? Just checked both methods and they work with 1.2.1 and 1.3.0

Comment: <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="@color/..."/>.

What color do I have to set there ?

Comment: @AshutoshYadav the color you want to achieve for not selected items.

Comment: I dont want any colors for the not selected items, actually I had used png they have own color, I just want it don't get overlapped by colors when we are selecting and not selecting it

Comment: @AshutoshYadav In this case you have to use `navView.itemIconTintList = null`